# Change SVG fill animation height depending on CSS class

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am using the following SVG and CSS code to animate the fill level of an SVG shape.

```css
.st0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-miterlimit: 5;
}

.st1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-miterlimit: 5;
}

#logo2 {
  width: 150px !important;
  height: 150px !important;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -100px;
}

#banner {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: -1;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}

#banner .fill {
  animation-name: fillAction;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#banner #waveShape {
  animation-name: waveAction;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  fill: #04ACFF;
}

@keyframes fillAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, -5px);
  }
}

@keyframes waveAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-150px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="banner">
    <div>
      <svg version="1.1" id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">

          <defs>
<clipPath id="drop">
                <path transform="scale(0.75), translate(32,0)"
                  d="M68.2,6.7c0,0-62.4,70.9-62.4,124.7c0,32.3,28,58.4,62.4,58.4s62.4-26.2,62.4-58.4
                    C130.7,77.6,68.3,6.7,68.2,6.7z M61,77.5c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v20.6c2.7-3.6,7.6-5.7,13.1-5.2,0,19.4,6.9,19.4,18.7v37.2
                    c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5H75.6c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.4-1.5v-32c0-4.1-1.8-6.4-5-6.4c-5.8,0-6.7,5.7-6.7,5.7v32.7c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5
                    H43.1c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5V79c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5H61z" />
              </clipPath>
          </defs>

          <g clip-path="url(#drop)">
        <g class="fill">
          <path fill="#04ACFF" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z" />
        </g>
      </g>
      <g transform="scale(0.75), translate(32,0)">
        <path class="st0" d="M68.2,6.7c0,0-62.4,70.9-62.4,124.7c0,32.3,28,58.4,62.4,58.4s62.4-26.2,62.4-58.4
C130.7,77.6,68.3,6.7,68.2,6.7z" />

      </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to and failing is to change the height of the "water level" animation.

So the preferred outcome would be to change the height of the animation with a CSS class, so I can animate 75% or 25% fill level. I tried to change the height via CSS but it gets ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By modifying the animation played you can change the level it will raise up to.
By changing the animation played by adding an extra class you can decide which one to play.

I modified the wave animation to stop because it got me seasick ish.

Key points:

I changed the animation style by adding an extra class that needs to be used together with the fill class. This will enable you to choose which class to use for which animation.

```
.fill.fill-25 {
    animation-name: fillAction25;
}
.fill.fill-50 {
    animation-name: fillAction50;
}
.fill.fill-75 {
    animation-name: fillAction75;
}
```

Then I changed the translation height of the animations for the relevant keyframes. You could can also use a calc method there `calc(155px / 100 * 25)` to calculate custom percentages.

```
@keyframes fillAction25 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 115px);
  }
}
@keyframes fillAction50 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 85px);
  }
}
@keyframes fillAction75 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 45px);
  }
}
```

```css
.st0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-miterlimit: 5;
}

.st1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-miterlimit: 5;
}

#logo2 {
  width: 150px !important;
  height: 150px !important;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -100px;
}

#banner {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: -1;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}

.fill {
  animation-name: fillAction;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.fill.fill-25 {
    animation-name: fillAction25;
}
.fill.fill-50 {
    animation-name: fillAction50;
}
.fill.fill-75 {
    animation-name: fillAction75;
}

#banner #waveShape {
  animation-name: waveAction;
  animation-iteration-count: 10;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  fill: #04ACFF;
}

@keyframes fillAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, -5px);
  }
}

hr {
margin-top:50px;
}
@keyframes fillAction25 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 115px);
  }
}
@keyframes fillAction50 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 85px);
  }
}
@keyframes fillAction75 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 45px);
  }
}

@keyframes waveAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-150px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="banner">
    <div>
      <svg version="1.1" id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">

          <defs>
<clipPath id="drop">
                <path transform="scale(0.75), translate(32,0)"
                  d="M68.2,6.7c0,0-62.4,70.9-62.4,124.7c0,32.3,28,58.4,62.4,58.4s62.4-26.2,62.4-58.4
                    C130.7,77.6,68.3,6.7,68.2,6.7z M61,77.5c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v20.6c2.7-3.6,7.6-5.7,13.1-5.2,0,19.4,6.9,19.4,18.7v37.2
                    c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5H75.6c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.4-1.5v-32c0-4.1-1.8-6.4-5-6.4c-5.8,0-6.7,5.7-6.7,5.7v32.7c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5
                    H43.1c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5V79c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5H61z" />
              </clipPath>
          </defs>

          <g clip-path="url(#drop)">
        <g class="fill fill-25">
          <path fill="#04ACFF" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z" />
        </g>
      </g>
      <g transform="scale(0.75), translate(32,0)">
        <path class="st0" d="M68.2,6.7c0,0-62.4,70.9-62.4,124.7c0,32.3,28,58.4,62.4,58.4s62.4-26.2,62.4-58.4
C130.7,77.6,68.3,6.7,68.2,6.7z" />

      </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div id="banner">
    <div>
      <svg version="1.1" id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">

          <defs>
<clipPath id="drop">
                <path transform="scale(0.75), translate(32,0)"
                  d="M68.2,6.7c0,0-62.4,70.9-62.4,124.7c0,32.3,28,58.4,62.4,58.4s62.4-26.2,62.4-58.4
                    C130.7,77.6,68.3,6.7,68.2,6.7z M61,77.5c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v20.6c2.7-3.6,7.6-5.7,13.1-5.2,0,19.4,6.9,19.4,18.7v37.2
                    c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5H75.6c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.4-1.5v-32c0-4.1-1.8-6.4-5-6.4c-5.8,0-6.7,5.7-6.7,5.7v32.7c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5
                    H43.1c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5V79c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5H61z" />
              </clipPath>
          </defs>

          <g clip-path="url(#drop)">
        <g class="fill fill-50">
          <path fill="#04ACFF" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z" />
        </g>
      </g>
      <g transform="scale(0.75), translate(32,0)">
        <path class="st0" d="M68.2,6.7c0,0-62.4,70.9-62.4,124.7c0,32.3,28,58.4,62.4,58.4s62.4-26.2,62.4-58.4
C130.7,77.6,68.3,6.7,68.2,6.7z" />

      </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div id="banner">
    <div>
      <svg version="1.1" id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">

          <defs>
<clipPath id="drop">
                <path transform="scale(0.75), translate(32,0)"
                  d="M68.2,6.7c0,0-62.4,70.9-62.4,124.7c0,32.3,28,58.4,62.4,58.4s62.4-26.2,62.4-58.4
                    C130.7,77.6,68.3,6.7,68.2,6.7z M61,77.5c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v20.6c2.7-3.6,7.6-5.7,13.1-5.2,0,19.4,6.9,19.4,18.7v37.2
                    c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5H75.6c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.4-1.5v-32c0-4.1-1.8-6.4-5-6.4c-5.8,0-6.7,5.7-6.7,5.7v32.7c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5
                    H43.1c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5V79c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5H61z" />
              </clipPath>
          </defs>

          <g clip-path="url(#drop)">
        <g class="fill fill-75">
          <path fill="#04ACFF" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z" />
        </g>
      </g>
      <g transform="scale(0.75), translate(32,0)">
        <path class="st0" d="M68.2,6.7c0,0-62.4,70.9-62.4,124.7c0,32.3,28,58.4,62.4,58.4s62.4-26.2,62.4-58.4
C130.7,77.6,68.3,6.7,68.2,6.7z" />

      </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use with calc method

```css
.st0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-miterlimit: 5;
}

.st1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-miterlimit: 5;
}

#logo2 {
  width: 150px !important;
  height: 150px !important;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -100px;
}

#banner {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: -1;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}

.fill {
  animation-name: fillAction;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.fill.fill-25 {
    animation-name: fillAction25;
}
.fill.fill-50 {
    animation-name: fillAction50;
}
.fill.fill-75 {
    animation-name: fillAction75;
}

#banner #waveShape {
  animation-name: waveAction;
  animation-iteration-count: 10;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  fill: #04ACFF;
}

@keyframes fillAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, -5px);
  }
}

hr {
margin-top:50px;
}
@keyframes fillAction25 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, calc(155px / 100 * 25));
  }
}
@keyframes fillAction50 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, calc(155px / 100 * 50));
  }
}
@keyframes fillAction75 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, calc(155px / 100 * 75));
  }
}

@keyframes waveAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-150px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="banner">
    <div>
      <svg version="1.1" id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">

          <defs>
<clipPath id="drop">
                <path transform="scale(0.75), translate(32,0)"
                  d="M68.2,6.7c0,0-62.4,70.9-62.4,124.7c0,32.3,28,58.4,62.4,58.4s62.4-26.2,62.4-58.4
                    C130.7,77.6,68.3,6.7,68.2,6.7z M61,77.5c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v20.6c2.7-3.6,7.6-5.7,13.1-5.2,0,19.4,6.9,19.4,18.7v37.2
                    c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5H75.6c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.4-1.5v-32c0-4.1-1.8-6.4-5-6.4c-5.8,0-6.7,5.7-6.7,5.7v32.7c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5
                    H43.1c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5V79c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5H61z" />
              </clipPath>
          </defs>

          <g clip-path="url(#drop)">
        <g class="fill fill-25">
          <path fill="#04ACFF" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z" />
        </g>
      </g>
      <g transform="scale(0.75), translate(32,0)">
        <path class="st0" d="M68.2,6.7c0,0-62.4,70.9-62.4,124.7c0,32.3,28,58.4,62.4,58.4s62.4-26.2,62.4-58.4
C130.7,77.6,68.3,6.7,68.2,6.7z" />

      </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div id="banner">
    <div>
      <svg version="1.1" id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">

          <defs>
<clipPath id="drop">
                <path transform="scale(0.75), translate(32,0)"
                  d="M68.2,6.7c0,0-62.4,70.9-62.4,124.7c0,32.3,28,58.4,62.4,58.4s62.4-26.2,62.4-58.4
                    C130.7,77.6,68.3,6.7,68.2,6.7z M61,77.5c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v20.6c2.7-3.6,7.6-5.7,13.1-5.2,0,19.4,6.9,19.4,18.7v37.2
                    c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5H75.6c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.4-1.5v-32c0-4.1-1.8-6.4-5-6.4c-5.8,0-6.7,5.7-6.7,5.7v32.7c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5
                    H43.1c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5V79c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5H61z" />
              </clipPath>
          </defs>

          <g clip-path="url(#drop)">
        <g class="fill fill-50">
          <path fill="#04ACFF" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z" />
        </g>
      </g>
      <g transform="scale(0.75), translate(32,0)">
        <path class="st0" d="M68.2,6.7c0,0-62.4,70.9-62.4,124.7c0,32.3,28,58.4,62.4,58.4s62.4-26.2,62.4-58.4
C130.7,77.6,68.3,6.7,68.2,6.7z" />

      </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div id="banner">
    <div>
      <svg version="1.1" id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">

          <defs>
<clipPath id="drop">
                <path transform="scale(0.75), translate(32,0)"
                  d="M68.2,6.7c0,0-62.4,70.9-62.4,124.7c0,32.3,28,58.4,62.4,58.4s62.4-26.2,62.4-58.4
                    C130.7,77.6,68.3,6.7,68.2,6.7z M61,77.5c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v20.6c2.7-3.6,7.6-5.7,13.1-5.2,0,19.4,6.9,19.4,18.7v37.2
                    c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5H75.6c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.4-1.5v-32c0-4.1-1.8-6.4-5-6.4c-5.8,0-6.7,5.7-6.7,5.7v32.7c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5
                    H43.1c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5V79c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5H61z" />
              </clipPath>
          </defs>

          <g clip-path="url(#drop)">
        <g class="fill fill-75">
          <path fill="#04ACFF" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z" />
        </g>
      </g>
      <g transform="scale(0.75), translate(32,0)">
        <path class="st0" d="M68.2,6.7c0,0-62.4,70.9-62.4,124.7c0,32.3,28,58.4,62.4,58.4s62.4-26.2,62.4-58.4
C130.7,77.6,68.3,6.7,68.2,6.7z" />

      </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```